# Does a morphism which induces an isomorphism between Hochschild homology also induce an isomorphism between cyclic homology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, hochschild-homology, cyclic-homology

In a 1998 [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802007.pdf)  by B. Keller,  the author consider the following problem in Section 1.4: Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $X$ a scheme over $k$. We can consider the cyclic homology as well as the Hochschild homology of $X$. He then asked

"If a morphism of schemes induces an isomorphism in Hochschild homology, does
it always induce an isomorphism in cyclic homology?"

In the paper the author mentioned that this problem was still open.

> > My question is: Is there any progress on the above problem now?